# ViewPager page curl

Tags: android, android-viewpager

simple question, is there ViewPager.PageTransformer that animates a page curl effect?

I've been looking everywhere, but I couldn't find it and wouldn't really know how to implement it myself...

Thanks in advance,
Cédric

Comment: can you show some image so that i can provide you the exact animation on view pager?

Comment: you can use this library for making animation effect in view pager:  https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

Comment: Yes, I have made a video of it :) https://goo.gl/photos/ZqnDLttcdUDNyFtz5 this is probably hard to implement, but I think a lot of people are searching after this

Comment: that's not exactly what I'm looking for, also it doesn't use the pagetransformer class

Comment: Yes, the video is the link in my previous comment :) is it not visible?

Comment: have you check this one :  https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: I did, however it doesn't include the animation I want, implementing the basetransformerclass seems pretty complex...

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution, still not found any, if you have please share.

Comment: @RishabhMaurya I am working on a solution for this.  It's definitely a little complicated because with page transform you can only manipulate the view; you don't have a drawing canvas to work with.  To get around this, I am creating a `PageCurlFrameLayout` so that I can override the draw functions and draw the page curl effect.  You'll have to use that with the page transformer.  There's also some clipping involved. Give me a couple days and I'll have something for you.

Comment: @krislarson That would be awesome :) I also did an attempt but soon found out you can only manipulate the view with some simple transformations and then I didn't think it was worth it anymore. Good luck with your solution!

Comment: @krislarson Best of luck !

Comment: @RishabhMaurya see posted solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think @Cédric was right — it's probably not worth it.

So I managed to get this working, but there's a lot of ugliness in there.

- There's some duct tape in the software architecture.  Because page transformers only work on views, the app depends on using a custom layout that can handle drawing the page curl.  So the transformer looks like this:

  ```
  public static class PageCurlPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {

      @Override
      public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

          Log.d(TAG, "transformPage, position = " + position + ", page = " + page.getTag(R.id.viewpager));
          if (page instanceof PageCurl) {
              if (position > -1.0F && position < 1.0F) {
                  // hold the page steady and let the views do the work
                  page.setTranslationX(-position * page.getWidth());
              } else {
                  page.setTranslationX(0.0F);
              }
              if (position <= 1.0F && position >= -1.0F) {
                  ((PageCurl) page).setCurlFactor(position);
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  }
- To get a realistic page-turn reveal, you have to use `Canvas.clipPath`.  I had trouble getting this to clip to the actual path when testing on an emulator.  I had to resort to testing on the device to see `clipPath` work correctly.  Even turning off hardware acceleration didn't work on the emulator.  This gives me low confidence that this will look right on all devices all the time.
- I just drew the curling corner with `dispatchDraw` in the custom layout.  That's probably not the best place to do it.  If I were taking more time, I would probably have a special decor view in the view pager and have that draw the curl.
- You might notice that the paging in reverse is faster than paging forward.  You might not like the animation speed in either forward or reverse.  Too bad — `ViewPager` doesn't have any methods to tweak the fling speeds, so you get what you get.  This is yet another limitation of using `ViewPager` for this sort of thing.

You can look at my project as a proof-of-concept that you can indeed get a page curl to work with a view pager and a page transformer.  Hopefully this will give you what you need to implement it in your project.

Project is here: https://github.com/klarson2/PageCurlWithPageTransformer

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I wanted it to be like photobook (Album) .

Comment: Still , this is fantastic .

Comment: The custom page curl layout is a `FrameLayout` so you can have your fragment show anything you want inside the layout.  If you want I can add a fragment that shows images.

Comment: Thanks, seems it's works, but with no effects, it's some kind of page flipping, but it's simply overlaps the text with no shadows, page corners, etc. Moritz code is more bigger than yours, don't you missed something in yours?) Seems it's not implemented all needed.

Comment: Super solution dev